# Is universality decidable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Is there a turing machine which can take any other TM T as input and decide whether T is a universal turing machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such Turing machine could exist. See Rice's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem.

Comment: The URL is broken (should be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).